# Magento 2: Create two packages for one product

Tags: magento2.3, shipping

I need your help.

A customer ordered exactly one product.
The product will be disassembled due to its size and shipped in two separate packages. Unfortunately, I cannot create two Magento packages for only one ordered product.
Is it possible to create packages without adding a product? It should also be noted that the products do not have a stock management system.

[image]

Greetings

Julius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple packages for single product shipment is already featured by Magento 2.3. To be able to ship a product into multiple packages, you have to enable the `Allow Multiple Boxes for Shipping`. However, this setting is not available in store wide configuration. Therefore, to enable this configuration in all products, you have to change the value in each product from the product edit page.

To enable the multiple packages for a single product shipment:

1. go to the product edit,
2. select `Advanced Inventory` under the `Quantity` field
3. find `Allow Multiple Boxes for Shipping` and set the value to `Yes`
4. Click `done`
5. Save the product